# Drop, clone, Draggable, continues to clone after dragging in new div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, clone, draggable, droppable

This is my first attempt at drag and drop with cloning an element.
I have gotten this far by reading articles and going through examples and other trouble issues posted on this site. But 1 thing has eluded me is the cloning of an image.
Once I drop the image into the new div, it clones and is still movable. but after i move the clone, it continues to clone new images, leaving an existing one behind in the new Div.
I have searched and tried many posts that had a similar problem to not do anything.
I believe that after I clone, it is still tied to the existing Div??

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var copy = 0;
    $(function () {
        $("#iWidget").accordion();
        $("#iWidget img").draggable({
            cursor: 'move',
            revert: 'invalid',
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $("#iBoard img").draggable();
        $("#iBoard").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                copy++
                var TemEle = $(ui.helper).clone().attr("id", $(this).attr('id') + copy);
                $(this).append(TemEle)
                TemEle.draggable();
                alert('drop id:' + TemEle.attr('id'));
            }
        });
    });


<div class="iPage">
<div id="iBoard">
</div>

<div id="iWidget">
    <h1>Network</h1>
    <div>
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Network/WRouterONLINE.gif" ID="WRouterONLINE" runat="server"  Height="30px" Width="30px" />
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Network/ModemONLINE.gif" ID="ModemONLINE" runat="server"  Height="30px" Width="30px" />
    </div>
    <h1>Servers</h1>
    <div>
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Server/ServerONLINE.gif" ID="ServerONLINE" runat="server"  Height="30px" Width="30px" />
    </div>
    <h1>Workstations</h1>
    <div>
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Workstations/AlienwareONLINE.gif" ID="AlienwareONLINE" runat="server"  Height="30px" Width="20px" />
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Workstations/PCONLINE.gif" ID="PCONLINE" runat="server"  Height="30px" Width="30px" />
    </div>
    <h1>Other</h1>
    <div>
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Other/PS3ONLINE.gif" ID="PS3ONLINE" runat="server"  Height="30px" Width="30px" />
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Other/BlueRayONLINE.gif" ID="BlueRayONLINE" runat="server"  Height="30px" Width="30px" />
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Other/TabletONLINE.gif" ID="TabletONLINE" runat="server"  Height="30px" Width="30px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out...
Added this to the droppable... accept: '#iWidget img',

Comment: it's perfectly fine to answer your own questions and mark them as accepted rather then commenting, it also makes it more clear to others that might find the question later.